# Springboot app is up but POST request always return "not found"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've got my spring-boot app running but every time I try to perform a Get request the returned result is "not found" and I have no idea why the path I specified aren't recognized, here are the relevant classes:

The Hero entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hero")
public class Hero
{
    @Id private int hid;//This is the table's primary key
    private PGpolygon area;
    private String spower;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private DBApp.PowerCatagory pc;
    private float power_level;
    private float luck;
}
```

HeroRepository class:

```
public interface HeroRepository extends CrudRepository<Hero, Integer>
{


}
```

HeroService class

```
package services;
import entities.Hero;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import repositories.HeroRepository;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class HeroService
{
    @Autowired//Injects the dependency
    private HeroRepository heroRepository;


    public List<Hero> getAllHeroes()
    {
        List<Hero> res = new ArrayList<>();
        heroRepository.findAll().forEach(res::add);
        return res;
    }

    public void addHero(Hero hero)
    {
        heroRepository.save(hero);
    }

    public Hero getHero(int id)
    {
        return heroRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void updateHero(Hero hero)
    {
        heroRepository.save(hero);/*If a hero with the same id
        already exists in the DB then the save() function
        will automatically update that same tuple.*/
    }

    public void deleteHero(Hero hero)
    {
        heroRepository.delete(hero);
    }
}
```

HeroController class:

```
package controllers;

import entities.Hero;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import services.HeroService;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class HeroController
{
    @Autowired
    private HeroService heroService;

    @GetMapping("/hero")
    public List<Hero> getAllHeroes()
    {
        //System.out.println(heroService.getAllHeroes());
        return heroService.getAllHeroes();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test()
    {
        //System.out.println(heroService.getAllHeroes());
        return "working!!!";
    }

}
```

and my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MyDBExcercise</groupId>
    <artifactId>mydbexxcercise</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I really have no idea why the paths I specified aren't recognized so your help will be very appreciated, thank you very much!

**Update:**
I've managed to make some progress thanks to @Atul K and now I'm encountering
the following error `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'heroController' defined in file [D:\Projects\Java\mydbexxcercise\target\classes\com\db\controllers\HeroController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.db.controllers.HeroController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`. 
These are the updated classes:

HeroRepository class:

```
@Repository
public interface HeroRepository extends JpaRepository<Hero, Integer>
{


}
```

Notice that the interface now extends JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository like last time(after looking at the console I noticed that Spring boot didn't manage to find any repositories, hence the change).
HeroService class:

```
package com.db.services;
import com.db.entities.Hero;
import com.db.repositories.HeroRepository;
import com.db.app.DBApp;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class HeroService
{
    private HeroRepository heroRepository = DBApp.getAppContext().getBean(HeroRepository.class);

    public List<Hero> getAllHeroes()
    {
        List<Hero> res = new ArrayList<>();
        heroRepository.findAll().forEach(res::add);
        return res;
    }

    public void addHero(Hero hero)
    {
        heroRepository.save(hero);
    }

    public Hero getHero(int id)
    {
        return heroRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void updateHero(Hero hero)
    {
        heroRepository.save(hero);/*If a hero with the same id
        already exists in the DB then the save() function
        will automatically update that same tuple.*/
    }

    public void deleteHero(Hero hero)
    {
        heroRepository.delete(hero);
    }
}
```

HeroController class:

```
package com.db.controllers;
import com.db.app.DBApp;
import com.db.entities.Hero;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.db.services.HeroService;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class HeroController
{
    private HeroService heroService = DBApp.getAppContext().getBean(HeroService.class);

    @GetMapping("/hero")
    public List<Hero> getAllHeroes()
    {
        //System.out.println(heroService.getAllHeroes());
        return heroService.getAllHeroes();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test()
    {
        //System.out.println(heroService.getAllHeroes());
        return "working!!!";
   }

}
```

According to the console, the reason Spring can't initialize HeroController is the exception the following code causes:

```
    private HeroService heroService = DBApp.getAppContext().getBean(HeroService.class);
```

I've no idea why an exception is thrown here so again, any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What is your REST end point you are making call ? Provide more details.

Comment: You have no POST mappings in the controller, only GET mappings

Comment: You're right I meant  GET requests, I've edited the post, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I only see `@GetMapping` in your RestController. If you want to use Post use `@PostMapping`.

If you're aim is to just fetch the list of data, use GET request as it is the standard convention.

Comment: Or use `@RequestMapping` annotation with `method` parameter.

Comment: Using PostMapping will yeild the same result. It uses the RequestMapping in the background and passes Method.POST itself.

Comment: I'm sorry when I said POST I meant a Get request, I want to retrieve the list of heroes that are stored in my DB, I'll edit the original post.

Comment: @DineshSinghShekhawat I'm unable to apply this change, it causes a mismatch between the returned type to the declared return type

Comment: @BitThinker483 Update the changes you have made.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is not able to scan though the annotations you have used, due to - packaging of your classes.

Though package of Spring Boot Application class is not mentioned above code snippet, so let's assume it's `com.example`. Then following 3 options using which this can be solved:

**Option 1: (Would recommended)** Then rename your `controllers`, `services` etc packages by pre-pending `com.example` to them, as `com.example.controllers` etc.

**OR**

**Option 2 (If don't want to change the packaging):**
Add below annotation to your spring boot application class along with `@SpringBootApplication`:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "controllers", "services" })
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "repositories" })
 @EntityScan(basePackages = "entities")`

**OR**

**Option 3 (Only for testing purpose) :** Move all your classes to `com.example` where your main boot application class is at.

Comment: About option 1, do all the names of my packages have to have a similar prefix in order for spring boot to scan them?

Comment: I've managed to make some progress but now I'm encountering a different error, please take a look at the updated post.

Comment: I am not able to see any update in the post. Can you provide stack trace? Also if its not 404, then please accept this solution and add a fresh question.

Comment: You're right, I'll post a new question, please take a look at it when you can.

Comment: Answered to your new question. BTW you can use CrudRepository instead of JpaRepository. I am able to hit endpoints without any issues.

Comment: @BitThinker483 kindly accept the answer if it has work for this question, otherwise won't be able to help you or others with comments of your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a `POST` call then you need to replace the following line in your code :

```
@GetMapping("/hero")
```

to:

```
@PostMapping("/hero")
```

That's all. Alternatively, you can also use the following piece of code if you want to use both `GET` and `POST`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hero", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

and:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hero", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: I meant a GET request, I wish the retrieve the list of heroes that is stored in my PostgreSQL DB, please take a look at my problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using @RequestMapping("/api") above your HeroController and access the method using "/api/hero" as GET request

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help as well. If it helps, every time I try to perform  a GET request, while the result is "not found" , messages regarding the initilization of the dispatcherServlet are being printed to the console.